# JavaFX 2: Ignore underlying node

Tags: javafx-2, drag

I have one node(ImageView) that displays an image and another node(rectangle) that resides on top of it. The behavior I need is that when the mouse is dragged(press-drag-release gesture) over the rectangle, both the nodes should move coherently. Is there a way to ignore the rectangle and just move the bottom node(I already have functionality to drag the rectangle along with the ImageView when drag is performed on the ImageView and that takes care of the rectangles moving along)? Any views will be  helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rectangle.setMouseTransparent(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent%28boolean%29).

The rectangle will no longer receive mouse events and they will pass through to your underlying ImageView which can intercept them and handle dragging appropriately.

If this does not answer your question, please edit your question to clarify it further (perhaps provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)).